# Removing Object from ArrayList causes lag

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an **ArrayList** which holds Planes (enemies) on my android game. These planes move from one side of the screen to the other and the user has to dodge them. When a plane's x value becomes less than -50 it is removed from the ArrayList. When this happens, it causes all the planes on the screen currently to 'jump' slightly. They disappear for a few milliseconds and then are re-drawn but 2px behind where they are supposed to be.

Here is the paint method, where planes is the ArrayList

```
public void onDraw(){
        bg1.onDraw(c);
    bg2.onDraw(c);
    chopper.onDraw(c);

    score.onDraw(c);

    // PAINTS THE PLANE OR DELETES IF OFF SCREEN
    for (int i = 0; i < planes.size(); i++) {
        Plane p = planes.get(i);
                    if(p.getX()<-50){
                            planes.remove(p);
                    }else{
                            p.onDraw(c);

                            if (p.getX() < 170) {
                                    detectPlaneCollision(p, c);
                            }
                    }

           }
}
```

Is there a way of fixing this? Should I use a different data structure?

Thanks

Tom

Comment: why don't you botter for 10 seconds and format properly your code

Comment: I tried, it formatted correctly as it was typed, I don't know why it has done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is nothing to do with your choice of data structure, but instead because **you are modifying your `List` while you're looping over it**.

Imagine you have three planes in your list - [P1,P2,P3].

- On the first iteration of your loop `i` is `0`, you process P1
- P1 has `getX() < -50` so you remove it, making the list now [P2,P3]
- On the next iteration of the loop `i` is  now `1` so you process P3.
- This means P2 never gets processed and so will never be drawn, making it disappear briefly.

Try using an `Iterator` which will allow you to safely remove items while looping over the `List`.

```
Iterator<Plane> i = planes.iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
  Plane p = i.next();

  if (p.getX() < -50) {
    i.remove();
  } else {
    p.onDraw(c);

    if (p.getX() < 170) {
      detectPlaneCollision(p, c);
    }
  }
}
```

Although, since you don't care about the order in which you process your `Plane` obejcts you could consider storing them in a `Set` rather than a `List`.  A `Set` doesn't have to worry about maintaining an order of items as you add and remove them.

Comment: Thank-you very much, I tried this and it worked. I have never heard of/used iterators before, so thank-you for showing me this!

Comment: These days you only need to use Iterators when you're modifying the list.  Otherwise you can say `for (Plane p : planes) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

If you do a lot of removing and adding from a list, consider using a `LinkedList`. An `ArrayList` is more suitable, if there's very little change in the dataset.

Although you must also consider the fact that getting elements from a `LinkedList` is somewhat slower than from an `ArrayList`, so keep that in mind when using a `LinkedList`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in that code.

What if `i==0` and `planes[0]` gets removed?

`planes[n]` will move into position `planes[n-1]`. E.g. `planes[1]` will move into position `planes[0]`.

Then `i` gets incremented, so `i==1`.

Therefore the original `planes[1]` (which is now `planes[0]`) will be skipped.

Comment: Ah of course, this could explain the skipping, as planes[0] is always the one removed!